# remove comma from end of json list in bash script

Tags: json, bash, sed

I have a bash script that output json, but apparently, I can't have a comma at the end of the list items as seen below. How do I get the last item in the list to not have a comma on the end, while keeping it on all the rest of the items?

Ideally, I'd like to do this in the loop, but I'm okay with stripping it off after creation.

Here is a portion of the script.

```bash
  #Print out a list of hosts in groups
  for group in $grouplist; do
    printf '\t"%s": {\n' $group
    echo -ne '\t\t"hosts": ['
    for host in `grep $group $results|awk '{print $1}'`; do
      printf '"%s", ' "$host"
    done
    echo ']'
    echo -e '\t},'
  done
```

It outputs a json list ending like this.

```
                    },
            }
```

I have this in a function so I have messed around with a variety of sed stuff to clean it up, but haven't managed to pull it off.

```
function | sed "s/something/another/"
```

Comment: Please adhere to the instructions given in [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will help you get better answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can get the len of `$grouplist` and keep track of the loop count, then echo with and if;then; else, something like this:

```
len=$(wc -w <<< $grouplist)
i=0

for group in $grouplist; do

    let i++

    printf '\t"%s": {\n' $group
    echo -ne '\t\t"hosts": ['
    for host in `grep $group $results|awk '{print $1}'`; do
        printf '"%s", ' "$host"
    done
    echo ']'

    if (( $i < $len )); then
        echo -e '\t},'
    else
        echo -e '\t}'
    fi

done
```